# Bing image search api filter size

Tags: c#, .net, bing, bing-api

I'm using the bing image search api to retrieve some images from bing. I want to retrieve the small images, medium or large, depending on the task that I want to achieve. However, it looks like I'm doing something wrong.

Here is my code:

```
            // This is the query - or you could get it from args.

            string query = keyword;

            // Create a Bing container.

            string rootUri = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search";

            var bingContainer = new Bing.BingSearchContainer(new Uri(rootUri));

            // Configure bingContainer to use your credentials.

            bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(uid, uid);

            // Build the query.


            var imageQuery = bingContainer.Image(keyword, null, null, null, null, null, null);

            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    imageQuery = imageQuery.AddQueryOption("Size", "Small");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    imageQuery = imageQuery.AddQueryOption("Size", "Medium");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    imageQuery = imageQuery.AddQueryOption("Size", "Large");
                    break;
            }
            var imageResults = imageQuery.Execute();

            foreach (var result in imageResults)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(result.Title + ":" + result.MediaUrl);

            }
```

I'm getting an error at `var imageResults = imageQuery.Execute()`

Here is the error `An error occurred while processing this request`

The imageQuery looks like this (when the exception is thrown): [Link](https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Image()?Query='flowers'&Size=Large)

It works without the filters.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If this is exactly the same code, it should not be compiled - there is a missing parenthesis after "Large"

Comment: missed that when I posted it here

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constructor :

```
var imageQuery = bingContainer.Image(keyword, null, null, null, null, null, "Size:Small");
```

Note that internally what it does is this:

```
query = query.AddQueryOption("ImageFilters", string.Concat("\'", System.Uri.EscapeDataString(ImageFilters), "\'"));
```

Where `query` is your imageQuery

So if you do not want to use the constructor, you should be able to switch cases (0,1,2) as follows:

```
var imageQuery = bingContainer.Image(keyword, null, null, null, null, null, null);

string imageFilters;
switch (i)
{
    case 0:
        imageFilters= ("Size:Small");
        break;
    case 1:
        imageFilters= ("Size:Medium");
        break;
    case 2:
        imageFilters= ("Size:Large");
        break;
}
imageQuery = query.AddQueryOption("ImageFilters", string.Concat("\'", System.Uri.EscapeDataString(imageFilters), "\'"));
```